# Getting longer error trace from logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

Are there commends for getting longer error trace from logcat? For example I am getting the error trace below, but apparently it is not enough to indicate what the problem is:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.site.pkg, PID:
>   10527 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary
>   XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
>       at com.site.pkg.MainActivity$Adapter.onCreateViewHolder(MainActivity.java:62)
>       at com.site.pkg.MainActivity$Adapter.onCreateViewHolder(MainActivity.java:53)
>       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5833)
>       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5057)
>       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4967)
>       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
>       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
>       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
>       at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
>       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3315)
>       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2843)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20171)
>       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
>       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20171)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20171)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
>       at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:389)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20171)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20171)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20171)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3143)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20171)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2644)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1599)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1891)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1487)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7450)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6:
>   Error inflating class fragment
>       at android.vie

Comment: seems like you just need to look here `com.site.pkg.MainActivity$Adapter.onCreateViewHolder(MainActivity.java:62) at `

Comment: that's not enough.  read the comments at the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513614/how-to-get-viewpager-to-behave-like-a-vertical-listview?noredirect=1#comment68340411_40513614

Comment: IMHO i would suggest to study about this  `InflateException` why this happen and study some example question and answer plus i guess there are some 3rd party libraries exist for logging (never used it) so maybe somebody else will guide you better :)

Answer (score 0):

A rule of thumb is that you can read from the top to bottom until you find a class that you know is yours and not in android internals.

Like in your stack trace you can find this line

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.site.pkg, PID: 10527 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file 
line #6: Error inflating class fragment at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) at 
com.site.pkg.MainActivity$Adapter.onCreateViewHolder(MainActivity.java:62) 
at
```

where the interesting part is `MainActivity$Adapter.onCreateViewHolder(MainActivity.java:62)`

so you should begin your investigation in your `MainActivity.java` at line `62`.

But in your case, where you have this error `Error inflating class fragment at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)`. 
Most probably something is wrong in the fragment layout which you try to inflate.

So check your layout xml file, look for errors, maybe you're trying to add a custom widget which is broken or doesn't exist (just a guess of course).

Hopefully I pointed you in the right direction at least.